# File write operations in mongo script?

Tags: mongodb

Is this possible to write the query result to the file from mongo js script. I have searched a lot, but I didn't find any solution.

ex:-

```
cursor = db.users.find();

while(cursor.hasNext()) {
  cursor.next();
  // writing the cursor output to file ????<br/>
}
```

Comment: btw, if you're always iterating the whole collection than it's more efficient to use mongodump. using a script is more flexible, you can do all kinds of processing before printing results.

Comment: more on [mongodump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991292/dump-mongo-collection-into-json-format)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You could use print and then redirect output:

script.js:

```
cursor = db.users.find();
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    printjson(cursor.next());
}
```

then run the script and redirect output to a file:

```
mongo --quiet script.js > result.txt
```

Comment: yes, it's possible. But i am trying to run the script as daemon. So only I asked for file write operations. thanks.

Comment: daemon process' output can also be redirected to a file. you could write a shell script around it, to invoke mongo on demo.js and redirect to a file.

Comment: How can I specify what database the script should use?

Comment: How do I import the data to another mongodb instance afterwards? :)

Comment: @NeluMalancea you simply can use any Mongo shell command line args. So to specify the database on a remote host, e.g.
mongo --host MYSERVER DATABASENAME --quiet script.js > result.txt

Comment: @NeluMalancea You can use ``dr= new Mongo("127.0.0.1:27017").getDB("dr")`` then you prefix your collections with dr. That will enable you to work with more than one database; i.e. read from one copy to another etc.

Comment: this answer doesn't fulfill the original intent. is there any way to write to a file from a mongo script?

Comment: @comiventor JavaScript cannot write files, well with Local Storage as an exception (NodeJs has it's own file package to do this)

Comment: @milan I understand the constraint from javascript perspective but isn't this too restrictive from mongo shell perspective? :( dunno why they chose JS for mongo shell

Comment: I prefer `mongo db.example.com/live --quiet --eval "db.foo.find().forEach(function(r){ print(JSON.stringify(r)) })" -u live -p $(< config/db_secret) > /tmp/foo.ljson` because it doesn't print a bunch of useless white space. Saves time and disk space, and now line count roughly matches record count. Also note this isn't ACTUALLY JSON, because each record dict is just concatenated without separator or enclosing list.

Answer (score 22):

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell paragraph "Differences between scripted and interactive/ Printing".

```sh
./mongo server.com/mydb --quiet --eval "db.users.find().forEach(printjson);" > 1.txt
```

Comment: This approach gets tricky if you want to put a query inside the find() because of the character escaping.  In that case, best to use @milan 's answer above with a separate query file

Comment: @AndrewL Can you use single quotes instead?  I think that's supposed to not do as much escaping or something, right?

Comment: For printing certain fields/custom-format, use: ".forEach( function(d) { print( d.id ); } );".

Comment: Yes, you can use single quotes eg in the find filter.

Answer (score 15):

Whenever I need to write the result of a mongo query to a local file I generally use the the `writeFile(pathToFile, stringContents)` function.

Example: let's say that you quickly need to find the email of all registered users and send it to your buddy Jim in the marketing department.

```
$ mongo mongodb://my-fancy-mongo-server --ssl -u fancy_username -p fancy_password 
successfully connected to my-fancy-mongo-server!
> emails = db.users.distinct('email_address')
> writeFile("jims_email_list.json", tojson(emails))
```

or if Jim expect's a CSV file then

```
$ mongo mongodb://my-fancy-mongo-server --ssl -u fancy_username -p fancy_password 
successfully connected to my-fancy-mongo-server!
> emails = db.users.distinct('email_address')
> writeFile("jims_email_list.csv", emails.join("\n"))
```

You can now send Jim the list of emails and save the day!

To important things to notice about the `writeFile` function:

1. The second argument must be a string.
2. The first argument must be a file that doesn't already exist, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: This sounds great, but where does `writeFile` come from? It is not defined in my mongo CLI. I also can't seem to find any documentation on it (but maybe I didn't look hard enough?). Perhaps I have too old of a mongo client?

Comment: Its part of the NodeJS fs API. See here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: Mongo often tends to add some more exotic functions without documenting them. ```writeFile``` is one such example. It is normal mongo shell function, just they decided not to document it. There is a lot of undocumented functions in mongo, including several more file system I/O functions, functions that allow user to input data from keyboard, functions that allow execution of OS commands from the mongo shell, and so on.
NodeJS is not implemented in mongo shell, because most other functions from NodeJS do not work in mongo shell. ```writeFile``` and a few more do, but very few.

Comment: It is just a coincidence that mongo shell has a couple of functions with the same name as NodeJS.

Answer (score 14):

You can skip the while loop using `forEach()`:

```
db.users.find().forEach(printjson);
```

Comment: Even more compact:
db.users.find().forEach(printjson);

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be simpler to use one of the [Mongo drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) for a general purpose language (such as Python, Ruby, Java, etc) and write your results to a file that way, in a format you can use (such as CSV, etc.)?

**UPDATE:** According to the documentation for [mongodump](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools#ImportExportTools-Example%3aDumpingaSingleCollectionwithaquery) you can export a collection with a query:

```
$ ./mongodump --db blog --collection posts
-q '{"created_at" : { "$gte" : {"$date" : 1293868800000},
                      "$lt"  : {"$date" : 1296460800000}
                    }
    }'
```

However you would need to import that collection back into MongoDB to operate on it or use [mongoexport](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongoexport) to export as JSON or CSV using the same query flag (`-q`) as `mongodump`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I want this to be in plain js which run using mongo shell.

Answer (score 2):

For distinct you have to create script.js file with contents:

```
mongo = new Mongo("localhost");
doctor = mongo.getDB("doctor");
users = doctor.getCollection("users");
cities = users.distinct("address.city");
printjson(cities);
```

then in console run:

```
mongo --quiet script.js > result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 14, 2024, you can do the following

```
cursor = db.users.find();
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    fs.writeFile('/path/to/your.json', JSON.stringify(cursor.next()))
}
```