# Dump Mongo Collection into JSON format

Tags: json, mongodb, dump

Is there any way to dump mongo collection into json format? Either on the shell or using java driver.I am looking for the one with best performance.

Comment: `mongoexport -d <database> -c <collection_name> --out <xxx.json> --pretty --host <host> --port <port> --username <user> --authenticationDatabase admin` You can specify the `host`, `port`, `username`, `password` like this and the default authentication database is `admin`.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Mongo includes a mongoexport utility [(see docs)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) which can dump a collection. This utility uses the native libmongoclient and is likely the fastest method.

```
mongoexport -d <database> -c <collection_name>
```

Also helpful:

`-o`: write the output to file, otherwise standard output is used ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-out))

`--jsonArray`: generates a valid json document, instead of one json object per  line ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-jsonarray))

`--pretty`: outputs formatted json ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-pretty))

Comment: Use the -d flag to specify what database to use.

Comment: If you want pretty printed JSON (e.g. to inspect a collection during development) use the `--pretty` flag: `mongoexport -d mydatabase -c mycollection --pretty`

Comment: If Mongo is located on a different host, here's an example from the Mongo doc

`mongoexport --host mongodb1.example.net --port 37017 --username user --password "pass" --collection contacts --db marketing --out mdb1-examplenet.json`

Comment: It seems like `--pretty` is gone as of version 2.6.10.

Comment: I guess this method exports in Mongodb extended JSON format. For example dates are like ISODATE("2021-12-...."). I had problems parsing this format with Apache Drill. I don't know if you can override the export to output in well-known JSON.

Comment: We have loads of collections, possible to just dump all collections?

Answer (score 141):

Use mongoexport/mongoimport to dump/restore a collection:

**Export JSON File**:

`mongoexport --db <database-name> --collection <collection-name> --out output.json`

**Import JSON File**:

`mongoimport --db <database-name> --collection <collection-name> --file input.json`

> WARNING
>   `mongoimport` and `mongoexport` do not reliably preserve all rich BSON data types because JSON can only represent a subset of the types supported by BSON. As a result, data exported or imported with these tools may lose some measure of fidelity.

Also, http://bsonspec.org/

> BSON is designed to be fast to encode and decode. For example,
>   integers are stored as 32 (or 64) bit integers, so they don't need to
>   be parsed to and from text. This uses more space than JSON for small
>   integers, but is much faster to parse.
>
> In addition to compactness, BSON adds additional data types
>   unavailable in JSON, notably the BinData and Date data types.

Comment: Is there an example of what “rich BSON data” would not survive a `mongoexport`/`mongoimport` round trip?

Comment: It adds support for data types like Date and binary that aren't supported in JSON. Also, faster to encoding and decoding http://bsonspec.org/

Answer (score 7):

Here's mine command for reference:

```
mongoexport --db AppDB --collection files --pretty --out output.json
```

---

On Windows 7 (MongoDB 3.4), one has to move the cmd to the place where `mongod.exe` and `mongo.exe` file resides =>
`C:\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin` else it won't work saying it does not recongnize `mongoexport` command.

Comment: Does anyone know of a formatter that will format normal json to the silly "single line no comma" format that MongoDB expects when importing?

Answer (score 3):

From the Mongo documentation:

> The mongoexport utility takes a collection and exports to either JSON or CSV. You can specify a filter for the query, or a list of fields to output

Read more here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongoexport

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little node script that I write to dump all collections in a specific database to the specified output directory...

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
import fs from 'fs';

const DB_URI = 'mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017';
const DB_NAME = 'database-name';
const OUTPUT_DIR = 'output-directory';
const client = new MongoClient(DB_URI);

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();

    const db = client.db(DB_NAME);
    const collections = await db.collections();

    if (!fs.existsSync(OUTPUT_DIR)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(OUTPUT_DIR);
    }

    collections.forEach(async (c) => {
      const name = c.collectionName;
      await spawn('mongoexport', [
        '--db',
        DB_NAME,
        '--collection',
        name,
        '--jsonArray',
        '--pretty',
        `--out=./${OUTPUT_DIR}/${name}.json`,
      ]);
    });
  } finally {
    await client.close();
    console.log(`DB Data for ${DB_NAME} has been written to ./${OUTPUT_DIR}/`);
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

Comment: how does this work for non local DBs? let's say I am using ATLAS... and want to connect remotely and create a copy on my local drive? do I need to install mongodb first locally? Can it be done without?

Comment: @DS_web_developer just add the `uri` parameter https://stackoverflow.com/a/64849825/14401