# How to merge from MongoDB to Firebase?

Tags: ios, json, mongodb, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently using MongoDB hosted with AWS. I'm looking to take all my users and their information to a new database (firebase). I'm not sure what steps do I take in order to do this. Any recommendations?

Thank you!

Comment: See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991292/dump-mongo-collection-into-json-format

Looks like firebase imports JSON based off of a google search.

Comment: thank you @dyouberg