# How to export data from mongodb to json

Tags: json, mongodb

I am a beginner and trying to import data from `MongoDB`. The `Robo3T` which I use for visualization shows something like below.

```
--Kins
    Kins
```

And this is the command I use

```
mongoexport --db kins --collection test --out output.json

mongoexport --db kins.kins --collection test --out output.json

mongoexport --db [kins].[kins] --collection test --out output.json
```

But none of them work. What's the correct syntax?

How to import data in json format. Please guide me.

Link I reviewed:

[Dump Mongo Collection into JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991292/dump-mongo-collection-into-json-format)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to import or export?

Comment: I am so sorry I wanted to export.

Comment: `mongoexport --db kins --collection test --host kins --out output.json`

Comment: It seems you want to export data to a json from a replica set instance: If that's correct use this: `mongoexport --host="rsName/rs1:27017,rs2:27017,rs3:27017" --collection=test --db=kins --out=output.json` [See docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#connect-to-a-replica-set)

Comment: @ambianBeing - yes you are right..

Comment: @Unbreakable go through the documentation link. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use the `--jsonArray` ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-jsonarray)) flag because by default mongoexport writes data using one JSON document for every MongoDB document.

```
mongoexport --db kins.kins --collection test --out output.json --jsonArray
```

You can consider using the `--pretty` ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-pretty)) flag too. It will output documents in pretty-printed format.