# Export database from MongoDb atlas to the local machine Monogo compass

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass, mongoexport

I have remote database in Atlas with name of "test" and I want to download collection name image_table as a JSON file.

In mac terminal:

$ mongoexport –db test –collection image_table image.json
I got the error>

020-01-16T13:49:12.822+0100 error parsing command line options: too many positional arguments: [–db test –collection image_table image.json]
2020-01-16T13:49:12.822+0100    try 'mongoexport --help' for more information

Comment: Did you run 'mongoexport --help' for more information.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I could find a bit more straightforward answer in Mongo Compass :

[image]

Just install mongo compass 
connect to your atlas remote DB: get the hostname like "cluster0-shard-00-00-rcapo.mongodb.net XXXXX" from your remote altas cluster then connect to the database.

then you can download each document as JSON or CSV format.
thanks, mongo DB compass developers team.

Comment: Any way to do this for all collections at once?

Comment: @iuliu.net you may need to buy Altas subscription to backup or download all collections.

Answer (score 18):

MongoDB Compass has many flaws and may fail you even with such a trivial task as exporting a collection. E.g. it will skip some fields in the export. The app itself says: "The fields displayed are from a **sample** of documents in the collection...". From my experience, a sample Compass uses is very small. I lost data even when exporting 100 documents or so.

Using `mongoexport` is easy. If you use mongo 3.6+, this will work:

`mongoexport --uri mongodb+srv://<username>@atlas-cluster-url.mongodb.net/<db-name> --collection <collection-name> --out <path-to-export>`

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem. In my case, I was using mongoexport with the --query option, which expects a JSON document, such as:

```
mongoexport ... --query {field: 'value'} ...
```

I needed to surround the document with quotes:

```
mongoexport ... --query "{field: 'value'}" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to export all the collections from my atlas to local database. After facing a lot of issues with mongodb compass and mongoshell I ended up using NOSQL booster for mongodb.
[Downloading Link](https://nosqlbooster.com/downloads)

It exported all the collections at once with ease and then I was able to import them into my local mongodb database using the same tool.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the Required Solution:

`mongodump --uri="mongodb://username:password@host:port/dbname" --out=/path/to/backup/directory`

This will dump all of your collections to /directory