# MongoDb Compass export db ref as embedded JSON

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-compass

Is there a way to export a collection with all DBRef Objects embedded in a single JSON?

I tried to export the collection from compass, but it does not resolve the dbrefs to embedded json.

---

Example of the data structures:

Process:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f44e89aa1f4c77447629a29"
    },
    "name": "test process",
    "description": "A test configuration for a process",
    "milestones": [{
        "$ref": "milestone",
        "$id": {
            "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc7b"
        }
    }, {
        "$ref": "milestone",
        "$id": {
            "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc82"
        }
    }]
}
```

Milestones:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc7b"
  },
  "name": "S1",
  "order": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "$ref": "resultDefinition",
      "$id": {
        "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc79"
      }
    },
    {
      "$ref": "resultDefinition",
      "$id": {
        "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc7a"
      }
    }
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc82"
  },
  "name": "S2",
  "order": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "$ref": "resultDefinition",
      "$id": {
        "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc7d"
      }
    },
    {
      "$ref": "resultDefinition",
      "$id": {
        "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc7e"
      }
    },
    {
      "$ref": "resultDefinition",
      "$id": {
        "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc7f"
      }
    },
    {
      "$ref": "resultDefinition",
      "$id": {
        "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc80"
      }
    },
    {
      "$ref": "resultDefinition",
      "$id": {
        "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc81"
      }
    }
  ]
}]
```

Phases:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc7c"
    },
    "name": "P1",
    "activityStream": {
        "$ref": "activityStream",
        "$id": {
            "$oid": "5f5755076b75033a49b7cc83"
        }
    }
}
```

ResultDefinitions:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc79"
  },
  "name": "userresult",
  "resultType": "User"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc7a"
  },
  "name": "planDateResult",
  "resultType": "PlanDate"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc7d"
  },
  "name": "fileResult",
  "resultType": "File"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc7e"
  },
  "name": "dateResult",
  "resultType": "Date"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc7f"
  },
  "name": "textresult",
  "resultType": "Text"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc80"
  },
  "name": "booleanResult",
  "resultType": "Boolean"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f5753636b75033a49b7cc81"
  },
  "name": "numberResult",
  "resultType": "Number"
}]
```

Relations:

Process can have n milestones. Milestone has one or no Phase. Phase has more nested paths, but not relevant for an example. Milestone can have n ResultDefinitions

Comment: you can do a aggregation query with lookup and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) all result in one collection, and then you can export that collection.

Comment: will this work recursively? Say I have nested references foo -> bar --> foobar where the relation from foo to bar is 1:n

Comment: yes this will work, also nested references will work, but depends on data, you can lookup collections using reference ids in single query, just test how much time its taking.

Comment: Can you deliver pseudo code to adapt it to a working example please? If you put this in an answer I will accept it and you'll get the bounty

Comment: ok can you provide schemas for all collections or document structure, so i will test and update you.

Comment: by schema do you mean an export of the analyzed schema in the collection with compass, or do you mean an example in json?

Comment: means example of fields and relation. or example of json documents for all collection, add only single single document for all collection, so that i can understand the relation fields to each other, and will make single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a aggregation query and use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator, this will copy query result in separate collection, you can modify your query as per your requirement, see the last stage is `$out: <collection name>`, just provide the name of collection and execute this query, this will copy result in that collection, and you can export that collectoin.

```
db.process.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$milestones" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "milestone",
      let: { id: "$milestones.$id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$id", "$_id"] } } },
        { $unwind: "$results" },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "resultDefinition",
            localField: "results.$id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "results"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$results" },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            name: { $first: "$name" },
            order: { $first: "$order" },
            results: { $push: "$results" }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "milestones"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$milestones" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      description: { $first: "$description" },
      milestones: { $push: "$milestones" }
    }
  },

  // you can specify the name of collection that you want
  { $out: "collection name" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Okdeoxm2hp_)

Comment: thank you! have you tried to import this into compass? (https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/import-pipeline-from-text/) 

I tried (and removed db.process.aggregate and the enclosing bracket) but it says FieldPath names may not start with '$'

Comment: ok what is the version of your mongodb? might be the down version is not supporting, will provide you another option.

Comment: docker image: mongo:4

Comment: can you try this one [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qZog-9bzjqo)

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Still not working - compass still complains about FieldPath names may not start with '$' 

I copied the query from your second playground link.

Comment: I am sorry for the problem, its causing because name of the field is `milestones.$id` that start from `$` in id, and they have corrected in 4.4 version, can you just try upgrading your compass version from [link](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass) or before you can try this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BwIMGqSbMNR) just updated one more pipeline, might be this will work. or try to execute query in mongo shell, they have also provided [mongo shell](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell)

Comment: The mongo shell is a zip download for mac osx which includes a file without extension? What is this? I made sure I have the latest stable version of compass installed. (1.22.1 stable on the download section) and in compass it says MongoDB 4.2.8 Community. 

What are you using? Only the playground? I noticed that the query works in the playground, but as I am a real noob when it comes to mongodb it is really frustrating that the import does not work.

Comment: Although the import of the pipeline does not work for me, the example seems to work in playground. Therefore I will accept your answer. Maybe you can try to get it working with the newest stable version of compass that I am using (4.2.8 / 1.22.1)

Comment: lol so sorry for that, might be there is issue from mongo community side about without extension you can post an issue about extension to mongo developer forum or i will ask to them, look at this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijTlX.png, same data and query executed in compass 1.21.2 and mongodb 4.4, its working,  might be they have corrected in 4.4. will update you if i will get some solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can Also Export Mongo Collection in JSON Format by this command,

```
mongoexport -d <db-name> -c <collection-name> --out <collection-name>.json
```

Comment: does this merge reference collection documents in single collection?

Comment: It's only for Single Collection Export in JSON.

Comment: OP wants to join reference collections document in single collection using reference ids. and your similar answers are already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991292/dump-mongo-collection-into-json-format), no need to answer again.

Comment: There is one solution for reference documents. run your query & then --out is generate the new collection. & then you can try this export JSON command.

Comment: Yes that what i suggested to him, the problem is not in export. he can export clicking on the button in compass.