# Transfer users from MongoDB to firebase

Tags: mongodb, firebase, firebase-authentication, mern

I have a native app/website with MERN stack.
Recently, I started working on the app from scratch (RN) and I was thinking to add Google/Facebook auth, I know I need firebase anyway but I have around 750 registered users.

I want to set up the login/registration with firebase only even for a simple email, but what am I supposed to do with the existing users?
Their info is stored in MongoDB with hashed password, any idea how to implement such a thing?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users you can import them using CLI

Comment: That looks like an answer @AmodGokhale :) Especially if you also link to the CLI command to do the same: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth

Comment: thank you guys! I'll try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert DB to JSON - [Dump Mongo Collection into JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991292/dump-mongo-collection-into-json-format)
2. Install Firebase CLI - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli
3. Run below command to import them into firbease ( Customize parameter based on your data format https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth )

> firebase auth:import users.json --hash-algo=SCRYPT --hash-key=`key`
> --salt-separator=`salt` --rounds=8 --mem-cost=14 --debug