# Redirect output of mongo query to a csv file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB 2.2.2 for 32-bit Windows7 machine. I have a complex aggregation query in a .js file. I need to execute this file on the shell and direct the output to a CSV file. I ensure that the query returns a "flat" json (no nested keys), so it is inherently convertible to a neat csv. 
I know about `load()` and `eval()`. `eval()` requires me to paste the whole query into the shell and allows only `printjson()` inside the script, while I need csv. And, the second way: `load()`..It prints the output on the screen, and again in json format.
Is there a way Mongo can do this conversion from json to csv? (I need csv file to prepare charts on the data). I am thinking:
1. Either mongo has a built-in command for this that I can't find right now.
2. Mongo can't do it for me; I can at most send the json output to a file which I then need to convert to csv myself.
3. Mongo can send the json output to a temporary collection, the contents of which can be easily `mongoexported` to csv format. But I think only map-reduce queries support output collections. Is that right? I need it for an aggregation query.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: If this is something you do frequently, you might consider writing a standalone EXE using .NET, python, or you could use NodeJs; each has a native driver that would make it easy to execute your code and produce the output desired.

Comment: I am referring to Zachary's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130849/convert-json-format-to-csv-format-for-ms-excel and am able to convert from json to csv. But as an alternative, can I output the json to a collection and then do a mongoexport?

Comment: I'd recommend you just build a small harness using Node and the MongoDB driver for NodeJS and then you can execute whatever code you'd like. You'd get the results you want very quickly without needing the shell at all. It would be very maintainable (and debuggable).

Answer (score 204, accepted):

I know this question is old but I spend an hour trying to export a complex query to csv and I wanted to share my thoughts.  First I couldn't get any of the json to csv converters to work (although [this](https://github.com/jehiah/json2csv) one looked promising).  What I ended up doing was manually writing the csv file in my mongo script.

This is a simple version but essentially what I did:

```
print("name,id,email");
db.User.find().forEach(function(user){
  print(user.name+","+user._id.valueOf()+","+user.email);
});
```

This I just piped the query to stdout

```
mongo test export.js > out.csv
```

where `test` is the name of the database I use.

Comment: How would I specify what db the User collection is in?

Comment: @NeluMalancea check out the MongoDB [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/) they have this information.  You can specify the DB by adding `use <database>` to the top of the script

Comment: Actually, since the shell helpers such as "use <database>" are not javascript, they're not permitted. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/. Instead, start your script something like this: conn = new Mongo(); db = conn.getDB('your_db_name');

Comment: @NeluMalancea the mongo command accepts a db url (and user, pass, …)

Comment: @NeluMalancea the `test` in the last command **is** the name of the database, just replace it with the name of your database.

Comment: I know this is old but this might help other peoples: You can use a host an a database name like so: `mongo your-host.example.com:27017/dbname`  where dbname is your database name and 27017 is the port of the mongod.

Comment: I had a textual field with lots of nasty user-input values with quotes and newlines, so I also defined a [string escaping function like this one](https://github.com/joliss/js-string-escape/blob/master/index.js) within my export script. It works, but I can't help feeling this is all getting very heavy. If MongoDB doesn't do this a more built-in way, then maybe saving as JSON and converting that file to CSV afterwards was a better idea.

Answer (score 132):

Mongo's in-built export is working fine, unless you want to any data manipulation like format date, covert data types etc.

Following command works as charm.

```
    mongoexport -h localhost -d databse -c collection --type=csv 
    --fields erpNum,orderId,time,status 
    -q '{"time":{"$gt":1438275600000}, "status":{"$ne" :"Cancelled"}}' 
    --out report.csv
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Hint: now it is `--type=csv` instead of `--csv`.

Comment: The limitation of the mongoexport is that you can't manipulate the fields. The mongo id exports as ObjectId(mongidstring). Being able to export the results from a mongo shell script is better if someone wants to manipulate the data of the fields (for example ObjectId(mongidstring).toString()).

Comment: can I do aggregation operations?

Comment: This solution worked. But for Windows I had to make two amendments: I just needed double apostrophe from outside and single apostrophes inside like this -q "{name:'stackoverflow'}" , also for port specifying -p command didn't work, I used --port 27000.

Comment: The Windows zip containing mongoexport is flagged by Virustotal as having Trojan-PSW.Agent - so not going to use that command personally.

Comment: Thanks @thisarattr. I explored with `mongoexport --help` command.
If anyone needs explanation to the command shared, you can take a look at below syntax:
`mongoexport --host=yourHost --port=yourPort --db=yourDbName --collection=yourCollectionName --type=csv --fields=CommaSeparatedFields --query='YourQuery' --out=outputFile.csv`

Answer (score 13):

Extending other answers:

I found @GEverding's answer most flexible. It also works with aggregation:

**test_db.js**

```
print("name,email");

db.users.aggregate([
    { $match: {} }
]).forEach(function(user) {
        print(user.name+","+user.email);
    }
});
```

Execute the following command to export results:

```
mongo test_db < ./test_db.js >> ./test_db.csv
```

Unfortunately, it adds additional text to the CSV file which requires processing the file before we can use it:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10 
connecting to: test_db
```

But we can make mongo shell stop spitting out those comments and only print what we have asked for by passing the `--quiet` flag

```
mongo --quiet test_db < ./test_db.js >> ./test_db.csv
```

Comment: Editing his answer would be better than adding a new one.

Comment: This works, but I'm getting `2022-05-20T11:19:13.288+0200 I  CONTROL  [js] machdep.cpu.extfeatures unavailable` as a first line even with `--quiet`

Answer (score 6):

Here is what you can try:

```
print("id,name,startDate")
cursor = db.<collection_name>.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    jsonObject = cursor.next();
    print(jsonObject._id.valueOf() + "," + jsonObject.name + ",\"" + jsonObject.stateDate.toUTCString() +"\"")

}
```

Save that in a file, say "export.js".  Run the following command:

```
mongo <host>/<dbname> -u <username> -p <password> export.js > out.csv
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971151/file-write-operations-in-mongo-script)

for outputing from mongo shell to file. 
There is no support for outputing csv from mongos shell. You would have to write the javascript yourself or use one of the many converters available. Google "convert json to csv" for example.

Answer (score 2):

Just weighing in here with a nice solution I have been using. This is similar to [Lucky Soni's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438389/5189714) above in that it supports aggregation, but doesn't require hard coding of the field names.

```
cursor = db.<collection_name>.<my_query_with_aggregation>;

headerPrinted = false;
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    item = cursor.next();
    
    if (!headerPrinted) {
        print(Object.keys(item).join(','));
        headerPrinted = true;
    }

    line = Object
        .keys(item)
        .map(function(prop) {
            return '"' + item[prop] + '"';
        })
        .join(',');
    print(line);
}
```

Save this as a `.js` file, in this case we'll call it `example.js` and run it with the mongo command line like so:

```
mongo <database_name> example.js --quiet > example.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following technique. It makes it easy to keep the column names in sync with the content:

```
var cursor = db.getCollection('Employees.Details').find({})

var header = []
var rows = []

var firstRow = true
cursor.forEach((doc) => 
{
    var cells = []
    
    if (firstRow) header.push("employee_number")
    cells.push(doc.EmpNum.valueOf())

    if (firstRow) header.push("name")
    cells.push(doc.FullName.valueOf())    

    if (firstRow) header.push("dob")
    cells.push(doc.DateOfBirth.valueOf())   
    
    row = cells.join(',')
    rows.push(row)    

    firstRow =  false
})

print(header.join(','))
print(rows.join('\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

When executing a script in a remote server. Mongo will add its own logging output, which we might want to omit from our file.
`--quiet` option will only disable connection related logs. Not all mongo logs. In such case we might need to filter out unneeded lines manually. A Windows based example:

```
mongo dbname --username userName --password password --host replicaset/ip:port --quiet printDataToCsv.js | findstr /v "NETWORK" > data.csv
```

This will pipe the script output and use `findstr` to filter out any lines, which have NETWORK string in them. More information on findstr: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr

A Linux version of this would use `grep`.