# is it possible to transfer the emails from the database to Mailchimp?

Tags: meteor, mailchimp

The tutorials i found online, teach me how to register users emails into my Mailchimp. but what if i already have those emails stored in the database and only want to transfer them? is it possible?

Comment: Google e.g. `mailchimp import email from database` to find all the possible ways to import data into Mailchimp.

Answer (score 1):

You want to export the mongodb database to a CSV file.

I did the exact same thing a while ago and unfortunately I can't find the code I used, but it was pretty simple. You want to use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18302533/183904