# How to write the file output to the server

Tags: mongodb

In MySQL I can do `select * from some_table into outfile 'myfile.csv'`
Is there something similar in MongoDB? Cannot find relevant information in the documenatation. I'm working with mongodb 2.2.3.

Comment: this might help .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478304/redirect-output-of-mongo-query-to-a-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `mongoexport`, which produces a JSON or CSV export of data stored in a MongoDB instance

```
mongoexport --db dbName --collection collectionName --jsonArray --pretty --query '{"key": "value"}' --output output.json
```

For more details, please refer to [mongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/).