# Mongoimport without mongoexport

Tags: json, mongodb, bson, mongoimport, mongoexport

Suppose I have ssh access to a server with mongodb on it.  However, suppose the server does not have `mongoexport` installed, and I cannot install it.  I can use `mongo`, interactively or feed it a script.  I wish to export a subset of the data and import it on my local computer.  Ideally, I'd like to run a script or command that saves the data in the same format as `mongoexport`, so I can import it with `mongoimport` locally.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12830385/513038 doesn't work (as it has extra line breaks in the results), nor does using `printjsononeline` instead, because some values get printed differently and I end up with "Bad characters" and "expecting number" errors when I run `mongoimport`.

Any ideas?  Again, I'd like to use `mongoimport` if possible, but other sufficiently workable ways are acceptable, as well.

Comment: If you are trying to export a collection, probably this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971151/file-write-operations-in-mongo-script

Comment: @Abhi Thanks, but `printjson` doesn't work, or at least I don't know how to import the results, anyway.

Comment: Can you transfer files? It would be easier to transfer the data files. To transfer them directly, the mongod should be stopped, but you can also use mongodump to create a BSON dump and transfer that. Using mongodump/mongorestore is preferable to mongoimport/mongoexport because the latter has JSON as the intermediate format, which is not as type-rich as BSON and so can lose type information.

Comment: @wdberkeley Unfortunately, the server ALSO doesn't have `mongodump`.  It only has `mongo`, `mongo_console`, and `mongos`.  Furthermore, it looks like the database is 300+ GB big, and it'd probably be a security hazard for me to have a full copy of it, anyway.  In any case, I eventually just manually copied some data over w/copy-paste, so I don't really need an answer anymore, though it'd probably come in handy in the future.